# Visa for baby US to Australia

Tags: visas, australia, children

I'm travelling with my husband and baby to Australia in a month, and we applied for ETA visas using the app, but my husband mistakenly put "No" under "Are you the applicant" for the baby's application. Now my husband and I have been granted visas, but the baby has not, and it looks like they think the baby is travelling with people who aren't her parents, since they are asking for forms giving permission for a child to travel without both parents.

What can be done to ensure that we get the visa? We submitted all the paperwork they ask for, but they say 90% of applications will be processed in time. Is there any way to speed this up? Can we fill out a new application and put the correct information this time? Anything else we can do?

Answer (score 4):

Since you already submitted the paperwork for the baby's ETA application, you shouldn't put in a new application.

Australian visa applications can't be expedited, and the embassy can't assist with visa inquiries.

It's likely that the baby's ETA will be approved in time for travel. However, I would encourage you to look at your airline's ticket change/refund policies in case your baby's ETA isn't approved.

Source: https://usa.embassy.gov.au/visa-faqs

Comment: In the end, the application was approved a day later, so all the worry for nothing! but thank you for your answer anyways